# Handle partial type with Boost Hana

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-hana

What I call a partial type here is something like that:

```
template < template <typename ...> typename Skeleton,
           template <typename ...> typename WrapperType,
           typename ... Pölicies >
struct MetaStorage {

  template < typename ... Ts >
  struct With_Type {

    using type = Skeleton<WrapperType<Ts...>, Policies...>;
  };
};

using partialType = MetaStorage<Sk, Wt, P1, P2, P3>;
using finalType = partialType::With_Type<T1, T2>;
```

I don't think it fits well with hana philosophy and it's not readable if I want to split the type more than this.

So what is the efficient way of doing this with Boost Hana?

Edit :

By that I mean, a way to allow user to create the final type in several steps. Like that they can use some partial type to generate every final type. But with the usual syntax and `hana::type`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the most efficient way of doing this"? Doing what?

Comment: @LouisDionne I hope the edit was more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Boost.Hana you can lift types to values with `hana::type` and the same with templates using `hana::template_`. With that you can do the following:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;


template <typename ...X> struct skeleton_t { };
constexpr auto skeleton = hana::template_<skeleton_t>;
template <typename ...X> struct wrapper_t { };
constexpr auto wrapper = hana::template_<wrapper_t>;
template <int i> struct policy_t { };
template <int i> constexpr auto policy = hana::type_c<policy_t<i>>;
template <int i> struct foo_t { };
template <int i> constexpr auto foo = hana::type_c<foo_t<i>>;

int main() {
  auto meta_storage = [](auto s, auto w, auto ...policies) {
    return [=](auto ...ts) {
      return s(w(ts...), policies...);
    };
  };

  auto partial = meta_storage(skeleton, wrapper, policy<1>, policy<2>);

  auto final_ = partial(foo<1>, foo<2>);

  skeleton_t<wrapper_t<foo_t<1>, foo_t<2>>, policy_t<1>, policy_t<2>> check
    = typename decltype(final_)::type{};
}
```

Personally I prefer to not bother with `hana::template_` in the cases where I can just use a function. I also use a macro to create a tag type along with its corresponding `hana::type` value to reduce some of the setup you see above the main function.

Comment: A lambda, returning a lambda... I should have done more Haskell when I could. That's literally the same than the structure but with value type, nice one! I'll just wait to see if Louis Dionne has something to add and I'll close this. Thanks :)

Comment: A template is a function on types. With Hana, function on types are represented as functions (here a generic lambda), so that would be the correct answer. Whether it's actually worth it to go the Hana way for something simple like this depends on your actual use case, I would say.